# Does this code duplicate an object or reference it?

Tags: python, object, reference

I have some code where an object contains two lists of other objects, and those two objects are closely related.  I want those objects to have references to each other without duplicating data.
In the following code, is

```
Parent.foo[0].bar
```

a reference to

```
Parent.bar[0]
```

or a duplication of it?

```
class Parent(object):
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.foo = []
    self.bar = []

def populate(self):
    for item in self.data:
        self.foo.append(Foo(item['foo']))
        self.bar.append(Bar(item['bar']))
        self.foo[-1].bar = self.bar[-1]
        self.bar[-1].foo = self.foo[-1]

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, an object once initialized takes only one physical position.
reassignments and passing as arguments will not cause multiple copies of the same object. in the same way, modifying the object in one location effects it in all other locations.

unless a deep copy is performed, the physical existence of the object in memory is not duplicated.

No, your code does not duplicate the objects. it just references in 2 different lists.

Hope this answers your doubt.

Comment: Meaning it is a reference to answer the question directly.